# Can we control EDS acquisition by DM scripting?

Tags: hardware, dm-script

I would like to control the EDS acquisition option on a DM system by scripting. In the case of an EELS acquisition, we can access to the EELS detector as a mere CCD camera, and thus an EELS acquisition can be controlled by Camera Control commands. However, an EDS detector can not be treated as a CCD camera, and I could not find appropriate commands from help files. Does anyone know appropriate scripting commands for an EDS acquisition?

It will be appreciated if you share some wisdom. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDS acquisition by scripting is currently not a supported feature and there is no documentation, but recent GMS versions provide the following commands you may try:

`Number EDSStartAcquisition( Number nChannels, Number disp, Number acqTime, Number continuous )`

`void EDSStopAcquisition( Number paramID )`

`Image EDSAcquireSpectrum( Number nChannels, Number disp, Number acqTime )`

As these are not officially supported, they may not work with all systems or under all circumstances. Use them at own risk.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt advice. I have tried to use these three commands on our JEOL-TEM system immediately. As the results, "EDSStartAcquisition" and "EDSStopAcquisition" worked quite well, but "EDSAcquireSpectrum" showed a error message. However, I can see the light of the end of the tunnel by your helpful advice.

Comment: By the way, do you know commands for controlling the EELS acquisition option without treating a EELS detector as a CCD camera? Current EELS acquisition option has an advanced function such as the "HQ dark correction", but Camera Control commands for controlling EELS detector as a CCD camera can not access such a useful option.

Comment: @kachigusa There are no dedicated EELS commands up to GMS 3.1. There are some EELS new acquistion commands documented in the help file of GMS 3.1 like `EELSAcquireSpectrum`, `EELSInvokeCaptureButton` and `EELSInvokeViewButton`, but the HQ dark-correction is not explicitly mentioned.

Comment: The HQ dark correction can be done "manually" though as well. What you need to do is to acquire a RAW (unprocessed) camera image and a high-quality dark-reference of your own, both you can do with the camera commands. There is nothing special with it. (The feature basically 'replaces' the short-exposure-dark-reference which is used both for cumulative acquistion or SI acquisition by a single, long-exposure quality reference, hence replacing systematic errors from summing X times over a reference with (identical) bad noise.)

Comment: I would like to appreciate your helpful advice about new EELS acquisition commands and a manual treatment of the HQ dark correction. Although the version of our DM system is GMS2, I'm going to try the new GMS3 EELS acquisition commands you mentioned. Could you show me the command arguments for new EELS acquisition commands "EELSAcquireSpectrum", "EELSInvokeCaptureButton" and "EELSInvokeViewButton"?

Comment: Documentation states they have been newly introduced in GMS 3.1, so I don't think you will have luck trying them. If you know a command, but not it's parameters, you can enter the command with *incorrect* parameter count (or type) in a script, hit ENTER, and watch the error-message in the results window. It will tell you what *expected* parameters there are - if the command itself was known. `Image EELSAcquireSpectrum( Number exposure, Number nFrames, Number spectrumBinning, Number verticalBinning, Number processing )`; `void EELSInvokeCaptureButton(  )`; `void EELSInvokeViewButton(  )`

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply and kindness. l have learned a great deal from you.